# jQuery click() issue on Safari but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm having a jQuery issue in Safari but not on Chrome so it's not a Webkit specific issue (or is it?)

I'm using [UniformJS][1] to beautify my form in http://results-estasporviajar.com/buscador.php

```
$("input, select, button").uniform();
```

Uniform hides the original element by a "opacitiy: 0" style and place a themed element instead. Safari is making a weird behavior: when clicking a element, it reloads the page without even waiting for the click to be released. If I remove UniformJS this doesn't happen. The most weird thing is that this doesn't happen in Chrome, FF or Opera.

I tried changing class, id and name attributes to double check none of my code is producing this behaviour. I tried

```
$('#destino').unbind('click');
```

but nothing changes.

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried preventDefault() on the event?

Comment: tried    $("select").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});    but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly but true this seems to be a bug within Safari

see the reported issue (#183) on [GitHub](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/183)

Good news is that it's already fixed in the nightly build of Safari...

Comment: To be more specific, the problem is resolved by removing a webfont from the <select> element. Thanks